Помогите с пониманием меры, Посчитать средневзвешенное строк внутри ранга
Прошу помочь в решении задачи, у меня есть таблица с порядковым номером и значением по нему, моя задача ранжировать по сумме значения, посчитать строки в визуальной таблице и вывести среднее значение суммы номеров строк для каждого ранга. Должно получится так:

Для row я использовала меру:
row = ROWNUMBER(
    ADDCOLUMNS(
        SUMMARIZE(
            ALLSELECTED('Таблица'),
            'Таблица'[число]),
            "Сумма", 'меры'[сумма сумма],
            "Rank", 'меры'[Rank]),
            ORDERBY([Rank], ASC))

для RANK:
IF(
    ISINSCOPE(
        'Таблица'[число]
        ),
    RANKX(
        ALL(
            'Таблица'[число]
            ), 
            'меры'[сумма сумма], , ASC, Skip
            )
            )

теперь я пытаюсь сначала посчитать сумму номеров строк мерой:
Мера = sumx(
ADDCOLUMNS(
       SUMMARIZE(
           ALLSELECTED('Таблица'),
           'Таблица'[число])
,"sum", 'меры'[сумма сумма], "rank", 'меры'[Rank]),
[row]
)

но результате не происходит группировка внутри ранга
Подскажите, как сделать вычисление внутри другой меры.

